# Building a React app that gets error loading data from API

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I'm doing this assignment in a React/JS course and I have to fetch data from open library.. I've built this function below that returns an object and a table which should load a book once you search for it.. but I just get "error failed to load" I can't find anything else in my console on what the error could be.

In my index.js I have the following:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './style.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import React, { strictMode } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
  const [selectedBook, setSelectedBook] = useState(null);

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };

  const searchBooks = () => {
    fetch(`http://openlibrary.org/search.json?title=${searchTerm}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const slicedBooks = data.docs.slice(0, 30);
        setBooks(slicedBooks);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  };

  const showBookDetails = (book) => {
    setSelectedBook(book);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={searchTerm} onChange={handleInputChange} />
        <button onClick={searchBooks}>Search</button>
      </div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>First Publish Year</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {books.map((book) => (
            <tr key={book.key} onClick={() => showBookDetails(book)}>
              <td>{book.author_name ? book.author_name[0] : 'Unknown'}</td>
              <td>{book.title}</td>
              <td>{book.first_publish_year}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {selectedBook && (
        <div>
          <h2>Book Details</h2>
          <p>
            <strong>Title:</strong> {selectedBook.title}
          </p>
          {selectedBook.author_name && (
            <p>
              <strong>Author:</strong> {selectedBook.author_name.join(', ')}
            </p>
          )}
          {selectedBook.publisher && (
            <p>
              <strong>Publisher:</strong> {selectedBook.publisher.join(', ')}
            </p>
          )}
          {selectedBook.language && (
            <p>
              <strong>Language:</strong> {selectedBook.language.join(', ')}
            </p>
          )}
          {selectedBook.subject && (
            <p>
              <strong>Subjects:</strong> {selectedBook.subject.join(', ')}
            </p>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is it `console.error('Error:', error);` that's showing the failed to load error or something else?

Comment: `Error: Error: Load failed ` when I search for a title..never seen it before and wondering if it could be related to the fetch of the API from Openlibrary?

Comment: What else _could_ it possibly be related to, when you get this when searching for a title. What does the request look like in the network panel? Does it get aborted somehow? If not, what response (status & body) are you getting?

Comment: App.js:35 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://stackblitz-starters-tk2xhp.stackblitz.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://openlibrary.org/search.json?title=Harry'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue for myself when I run your code using stack-snippets or th link you sent. `fetch()` will only return a rejected promise for network errors, such as permission problems. Perhaps try running your code in a separate or incognito browser to make sure a browser extension isn't interfering in some way as well.

Comment: Will try that, trying to use https in the URL instead of the API to see if it helps.. thanks anyway :)

Comment: @SterlinkArcher yeah, good idea to use `https://` for your API

Answer (score 1):

After fault tracing I found the error... ironically it was one letter missing from my API-call in the URL.

```js
App.js:35 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://stackblitz-starters-tk2xhp.stackblitz.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://openlibrary.org/search.json?title=Harry'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Then I just added an "S" to the URL instead of calling it over HTTP I used HTTPS....